# Prop.test alternative

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, proportion

I want to test if the proportion estimated by (600/100000) is less than 0.6.

- With `prop.test(600, 100000, p=.6, alt="greater", correct=FALSE)`, p-value = 1.
- With `prop.test(600, 100000, p=.6, alt="less", correct=FALSE)`, p-value < 2.2e-16.

So I suppose that to test the hypothesis of (600/100000) less than .6, I have to use `"greater"` as alternative. Right?

Answer (score 2):

```
prop.test(600, 100000, p=.6, alternative = "less", correct=FALSE)

    1-sample proportions test without continuity correction

data:  600 out of 1e+05, null probability 0.6
X-squared = 147015, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true p is less than 0.6
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.000000000 0.006415277
sample estimates:
    p 
0.006
```

Comment: Also binom.test(600, 100000, p = 0.6, alternative="less")